# Sink to tub conversion

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

I’m interested to know how in depth it would be to convert a bathroom vanity sink to a freestanding tub. Trying to plan a bathroom remodel and want to know my limitations on placement

Comment: A lot of variables. Picture and dimensions of existing room would help.

Comment: Drain pipe is probably not the required size, for a start. Also likely a foot or so too high.

Comment: Well for one thing, a tub is likely to take up way more space than a vanity, unless it's a double sink vanity.